# Can I use a lower ratio of coolant to water in a hot climate? (N. Texas)

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, antifreeze, additive

I'm looking at a fluid flush for my 2010 Nissan Altima. I want to ask if there are concerns or benefits to using a lower coolant ratio. I travel to Kansas for the holidays, where it's quite a bit colder in the winter. I stay for several days.  Also, do you recommend additives for the water flush portion, and for how long to flush with water before adding coolant again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Coolant formulation is just as the terminology suggests. It's not "only" anti-freeze, but a combination of chemical substances which provide optimum heat transfer as well. The ratio recommended for a specific manufacturer's product will cover hot and cold weather equally well, unless otherwise specified on the label.

As you've created two questions in one post, I have answered only the one with which I am familiar. Perhaps a second post to ensure compliance with the rules is in order.

Comment: Don't forget corrosion protection.

Comment: Antifreeze raises the boiling point  , so it is important in hot weather as well as cold.